# ASP.NET MVC (Razor) vs Angular 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, razor

We are currently considering moving from ASP.NET MVC to Angular 5, mostly because it seems like the best and latest framework. However none of us seems to be able to come up with hard reasons on why Angular is better than MVC (Razor).

SPA vs MPA seems like different approaches with neither really being *better* - just better at different things.

Are there any resources/comparisons with hard benefits between the two?

**Update:** Almost 2 years after moving to Angular 4 (currently 7) I can say that it was a great decision. Angular makes it super easy to write quite complex front-end applications and the tooling around Angular itself, TypeScript, Karma + Jasmine (unit test frameworks) is fantastic. SPA is a huge step ahead of MPA in my opinion - we can finally have fluid web experience. I never really liked Razor and the whole mess around ajax/jquery, but I can comfortably say that I am really enjoying my time now! .NET CORE 3 + Angular 7 gives us everything we need!

To anyone thinking of taking the plunge, I would strongly recommend Angular (might as well start with 8 or 9, which is current at the time of writing this).

Happy to add more details if people want them :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Razor view vs AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957898/asp-net-mvc-razor-view-vs-angularjs)

Comment: Somewhat, yes. It's just whenever I see such questions, the answers seem quite opinionated and make it really hard to come up for an argument for one or the other. SPA seems like better UX compared to MPA, but other than that, it seems very difficult to be able to say that one is better than the other. I would love to move to Angular as it just *seems better* and also the direction in which a lot of companies are moving. If someone was to ask me on why, I would not be able to give a clear answer however

Comment: Razor is just a view engine, which you can replace, if you so desire. Angular is a javascript framework. You can use Angular on top of Razor. You do not have to decide between the two. 
Eventually it all comes down to a) what is required by your specification and b) allowed by your budget.

Comment: we used both and made the transition to Angular + Web API (from pure .NET MVC).
One thing you have to keep in mind. Coming from a C# (MVC) background Angular has steep learning curve. Add RxJS to that mix and it gets even steeper. And depending on your JS knowledge: C# and JS are just different and you have to learn this differences

Comment: That is very interesting. What was the main driving force behind the transition? Were there any specific problems that plain .NET MVC could not solve for you? I am just really trying to understand the benefits of Angular and hopefully be able to convince my fellow team members to move into that direction, however I do not want to do that without clear benefits. SPA seems the main Angular advantage. It's component-based, more modular architecture also seems nicer... but I am not sure on what else really.. Plenty of drawbacks as you've mentioned!

Comment: Just adding my two cents: with SPA you usually use thin API so your server does less work because it doesn't have to render html and therefore uses less bandwidth.

Comment: I'm struggling too, but right now the limiting factor for me is the Identity and Authorization capabilities in ASP.NET MVC. We use Identity and the "AspNetUsers" model. We use the `[Authorize]` attributes extensively and have extended that to protect actions on our controllers. It seems in order for that to really work properly, MVC needs to do the routing? Which means your controller actions need to have Views? (i.e., `.cshtml` files) And in there we use the Angular... but still experimenting.

Comment: Can somebody explain what is more secure? MVC dll or Angular???

Comment: I went through this not too long ago. In the end, I added Angular to the arsenal, but it did not replace MVC. When we started a new project, the requirements indicated that it'd be very heavy on the client (panels with previews, display images, etc), so I used Angular and MVC WebApi - all great. On another project, we learned that it was mostly backend work (generating reports, simple CRUD, etc). MVC was good enough to handle it easily.

Comment: Why not go for Blazor? Component based SPA using C#: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor

Comment: Lots more Angular libraries, much more mature tech. Always hated the whole ASP.NET horrible template syntax. Personal preference I guess. Also it completely decouples front and back-end, meaning we can have people that specialize in both

Comment: I worked with both. I like the Javascript debugging in VS 2019. Now use Web Components with MVC. Thats Future Proof. Web Components are the NEXT big thing. If you combine them with Vanilla Javascript then Angular will become obsolete. Angular is NOT W3C. Dont like Typescript either. Javascript is dynamic by design. Now its raped by Typescript to make it static, thats wrong. Yes Dynamic has its problems but live with it. For a Pro that should be no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

6 months on from moving from ASP.NET MVC to Angular 5 (now 6) and we are extremely happy with the decision. .NET core backend and Angular frontend is a fantastic combination. It is so much cleaner and easier to create re-usable, strongly-typed, testable and easy to modify UI components!

For anyone considering if it's worth taking the plunge - I would say a resounding 'yes'!

Comment: it's been a year now, still happy with the decision?  We're contemplating the same move you made a year ago.

Comment: Yep - super happy with the move. Even more so now than 6 months ago. Angular 6+ is fantastic. Dotnet core + Angular 2+ is a fantastic combination!

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough points to make a comment but thought the following might help you in making a decision.

Just to note that if you use Angular CLI (The default Angular project in Visual Studio) you will lose the ability to use razor within the HTML. Something you was able to do before Angular CLI.

I do like using Angular but miss having Razor to omit certain parts of the HTML, for example, if the user didn't have the necessary roles or permissions:

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{

}
```

You can hide the HTML using Angular of course, but having it completely removed from the HTML itself is preferable in my opinion.

Comment: Good point. We are not using the .Net Angular project template, which we found confusing and unnecessarily complex. We split the two projects completely and have them in separate folders, which makes it easier to track changes/etc. I do agree that this sort of feature is nice in Razor and that there's a bit more work in angular to do that. At the end of the day - user role checking/protection ends up in the API, which should be the ultimate judge on what a user can and cannot do

Comment: Certainly Ross for sure, checking security/permissions on the server side is an absolute must. I don't have enough points to make a comment on your final answer below, but thought you might be interested in the following tool we like to use called Typewriter.

We like to use it to auto generate our Typescript dtos we use in Angular. The dtos are based off of our c# models. Very handy and saves a lot of time.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=frhagn.Typewriter

Answer (score 4):

I vote for an ASP.Net MVC Web Application in the cloud [Core or whichever] , and use of razor pages as needed. That is it. Case closed.

Even if the whole world runs after Angular , Aurelia, React, Node, Strawberry, Pistachio, butterscotch JS, I will not.

After all, JavaScript is spagetti and Angular is the Flying Spagetti Monster

based on personal experience and intuitive take.

Now please don't get started about mouse hover over page areas,

Comment: This is more of a rant than an answer.

Comment: I understand your frustration. I do personally prefer controlling the output of my HTML using Razor. It's all about the actual application and architecture.

Comment: May be its rant but I like the Flying Spagetti Monster phrase :-). By the way Javascript is not Spagetti anymore. It has Classes. Put everything in those classes and you will be fine :-)

Answer (score 3):

What I did found out about Angular vs MVC (Razor), I can work with both :-)

- **Authorization**: One thing to make sure is that you don't have complex authorization schemes. On the backend its easy to do your authorization on pages with Razor (even more with Core). Its more difficult to handle authorization with Angular because you will have to do it (and keep in sync) on both sides: client and server. Example: One thing you want is hide everything a user is not allowed to do. If you have a simple webapp and use a Masterpage: show only the menu items a user is allowed to see. Thats a very easy task to do in Razor. It takes more time/effort to implement this in Angular.
- **Templates**: Razor is extremely easy to use with templates. If you develop a website that must be used a number of times but with different layouts that can be done very easily with Razor.
- **Maintenance**: With MVC you have one application. The frontend and backend are one. For maintenance you will have a Angular frontend and X Backend, so two. That seems more costly from installation, maintenance, etc. point. If you have a simple application I would say KISS: Keep It Simple Suckers.
- **One**: In MVC the frontend and backend belong together. That can be good or bad. If you have one application with no dependencies on other things I think MVC is a good choice.
- **Future proof**: Angular is NO W3C and NOT baked in the browser. Because of Future proof solutions there is a strong interest in Vanilla Javascript together with **Web Components**. With MVC you can use this technology. ***Read about Microsoft FAST Design. It works great with MVC***.
- **SPA/MPA**: Thats not a point anymore. An MPA can also be flicker-free with libraries like PJAX etc.
- **Speed**: With MVC no wait time because Shit has to be loaded. Enough bad Angular websites already exists because loading takes ages.
- **...**: After working with Angular 9 I don't get the point of Angular. I don't know why you should go from MVC to Angular. Visual Studio has great support for MVC and is much better as VS Code. From productivity point I can produce much faster code with MVC as with Angular. If you have multiple front ends that must connect to the same backend may be then I can see the point. But even then MVC can be moduled and even can dynamically load them.

**htmx** Wow, now we are talking! Yes this is what we want. Let Html take back control how pages are loaded. Think this is the way to go. Worked a sample with NodeJS and are very exited about it.

**Update: I just did a nodejs/express/mongodb project and it beats it all. I am an expert mvc developer, but developing faster, better on a chromebook of 220e with vs code. now I know why it's so popular. and guess what? it's free. and guess what else? part of dotnet Core is based on nodejs. the console app is the same as a nodejs server. both you will have to put behind a proxy of IIS, Apache or NGINX.**

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I learnt during the comparison of MVC and Angular, among various factors, is that hosting MVC application requires a compute power container like Azure Web App, docker etc, while an Angular App can be deployed in any storage like Blob, CDN etc. When Angular is built, it gives a collection of javascript files, which are perfect candidate for storage container. They do not need compute power at all, which are the most costly resource in cloud world. CDN or Blob exposes Rest API endpoint to any of its underlying resource. So, the Angular will also be exposed as an API, which is all we want.

However, angular alone will not generate dynamic web pages. We need Web-Api at back-end to give the data. This can be achieved by a server-less solution (Function Apps, Logic Apps etc) or by containerization (Docker).

One downside that I personally found that the first time load of the Page in Angular is bit slow. After that it is really smooth.

All in all, I will vote for Angular/React and .Net Core in my future Web projects.

Comment: Really good points! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: You are mixing things up. Angular is Client. MVC is client and Server. There are also big negative things about Angular. What if you dont neex a webapi etc.

Comment: If a WebAPI is not needed, then the web-page is more likely to be static. Even then Angular/React should be better than MVC. Client-side rendering versus server side rendering. Former is always faster.