# How to migrate the ASP.NET MVC View to Angular UI

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, architecture

We are followed by 3 layer architecture in our project with MVC.

- For the UI we are using normal MVC view.  how to integrate Angular in the project?

Once Angular integrated then how we can pass the data from Controller to Angular. is it the right way pass the data controller to UI by the help of "JsonResult" or any other way is there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Razor view vs AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957898/asp-net-mvc-razor-view-vs-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to expose the service which will give json data as responses and will be binded to the page

You have to create services in angular that will call the .net backend services

Your UI and the .Net project will be seperated here